# Dynamic SQL - Concatenate a variable and a string together for a varchar column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am struggling to get this code to work, not sure how to do it in PL/SQL like T-SQL, ive tried both:

```
-- input the Application name 
SET CustomRoleName = 'FakeApplicationName';

-- create the base custom roles
create role identifier($CustomRoleName) comment = 'This is ' || $CustomRoleName || ' read-only role';
```

but get error:

> Syntax error: unexpected '||. (line 14)

and

```
-- input the Application name 
SET CustomRoleName = 'FakeApplicationName';

-- create the base custom roles
create role identifier($CustomRoleName) comment = 'This is ' + $CustomRoleName + ' read-only role';
```

but get error:

> Syntax error: unexpected '+'. (line 14)

Cant find anything on the internet about concatenating a variable in Snowflake for a varchar column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Snowflake Scripting:

```
DECLARE
   CustomRoleName    STRING DEFAULT 'FakeApplicationName';
   QUERY        STRING;
BEGIN
   QUERY:= REPLACE(
          'create role <role_name> comment = ''This is <role_name> read-only role'';'
          ,'<role_name>', :CustomRoleName);    

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
   
   RETURN :QUERY;
END;
```

Output(classic UI):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Never knew about Snowflake Scripting....Is it safe to assume when using Snowflake for dynamic t-sql equivalent to default to using Snowflake scripting?

Comment: @DuckDBAT55 Glad to hear it :) EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is a direct equivalent of dynamic SQL

Comment: Couple extra questions! Does this consume compute? Also, do i specify role context in the query beforehand? Looks like USERADMIN doesnt have permissions to run snowflake scripting?

Comment: @DuckDBAT55 Yes, it requires a running Warehouse. The user that is supposed to create a role  needs the right to create a role. Does the same user get an error when running direct: `create role FakeAppName comment = 'This is FakeAppName read-only role';`

Comment: No error as I am using the USERADMIN role which is allowed to create the role explicitly but not allowed to run snowflake scripting code since it doesnt have access to a warehouse. Im new to snowflake so im not sure if granting USERADMIN role to a warehouse is a smart thing to do in regards to security best practices